# Creating a list of 'unioned' elements of another list

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, reduce

I am still a bit green in programming and have hit a stumbling block.

I have a list of lists, and I would like to combine elements that have have similar elements in the nested list.

List of lists:

```
    x = [[25, 26],[26, 27],[27, 28],[32, 33],[33, 34],[40, 41],[61, 62],[62, 63],[63, 64]]
```

Output I am looking for:

```
[[25,26,27,28],[32,33,34],[40,41],[61,62,63,64]]
```

I've approached this a few different ways using lambda functions, map, reduce and map-reduce.

- I've tried mapping with a lambda function using intersection, but it does not capture all of the elements above 2. ie. x[0] does not have an intersection with x[2]
- The map-reduce gives me only the first set and the last index, I can iterate over this, but it seems very cumbersome, it also skips the sublists with no similar intersecting sublists. (example below)

```
mapped = [(idx, i) for idx, i in enumerate(x)]

reduce(lambda a,b: a if not set(a[1]).intersection(set(b[1])) else (a[0]+b[0],set(a[1]).union(set(b[1]))) ,mapped)
```

Output:

```
(3, {25, 26, 27, 28})
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: First question: "similar" is a vague term. It seems that you mean pairs of the form [[a,b],[b,c]], where c-b == b-a == 1. Is this correct? If not, can you define "similar"?

Comment: Second question: As you present the data, the sub-lists to be combined are all adjacent and sequential. Are we allowed to presume that this will be generally true, or should we account for arbitrary ordering of the pairs?

Comment: Hi! Yes, thanks for the call-out. All of the sublists will be in order. They are actually indices of another list of lines of text and they will need to be combined sequentially. The sublists to be combined will be adjacent to each other and by 'similar', I mean that the preceding element x[n+1][0] ==  x[n][-1], and when combined  each sublist will be a list of unique sequential numbers.

Comment: In that case, it seems to me that your first step would be to throw away the second element of each pair, since it's just a distraction, which gives you a list like `[25, 26, 27, 32, 33, 40, 61, 62, 63]`. Now you just need to partition this into sublists at the points of discontinuity and add in an extra "page" at the end of each sublist. It's possible there's a cute way to do this with higher-order functions, ie itertools, but it's also a simple function to write.

Comment: Or, possibly simpler conceptually, flatten the list, set-ify it, and sort the result. This is certainly not going to be more efficient, but it may well produce clearer code, which is usually more important.

Answer (score 0):

I think for this kind of problem, an imperative-style solution is most straightforward, rather than trying to do it with comprehensions or higher-order functions.

Here's a solution which builds a list of lists. Each time we see a new pair `[x, y]`, check if `x` is at the end of the current list. If it is, append `y` to that list; otherwise, start a new list with `x` and `y`.

```py
def join_pairs(pairs):
    out = []
    for x, y in pairs:
        if out and out[-1][-1] == x:
            out[-1].append(y)
        else:
            out.append([x, y])
    return out
```

Example:

```py
>>> pairs = [
...     [25, 26], [26, 27], [27, 28], [32, 33], [33, 34],
...     [40, 41], [61, 62], [62, 63], [63, 64]
... ]
>>> join_pairs(pairs)
[[25, 26, 27, 28], [32, 33, 34], [40, 41], [61, 62, 63, 64]]
```

As Jon Kiparsky has pointed out in the comments, the pairs in your example are conveniently adjacent and sequential. The solution above rather depends on that; if it's not true for all of your input data, then you will need to do some sorting first:

```py
    for x, y in sorted(sorted(p) for p in pairs):
        # ...
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it works! Question though - in the if statement. The 'out', is the list 'so far', and you are comparing the list 'so far'  AND the last digit in the last list to the first digit in the next pair to be checked. Shouldn't that never equate to true? ie. '[[25, 26, 27, 28], [32,33]]' and '33' == '33'...true? I mean.. it works, but why?

Comment: The `and` has a lower precedence than `==` - read it like `if (out) and (out[-1][-1] == x):`. The first part is just to check if the list has anything in it, otherwise `out[-1]` would be an IndexError.